# How can I fix this git remote branch tracking inconsistency?

Tags: git, github, branch, tracking, git-remote

I have a `git` repository that seems to be confused about its branch tracking configuration, and I need some help straightening it out. I'm running `git version 2.21.0.windows.1`.

The problem is that `git branch -a` still lists a remote I deleted, and it shows branch tracking that is inconsistent with `git remote -v` and `git remote show origin`. Below are commands showing the current state of the repo:

```
C:\dev> git branch -a
* dev-mdbootstrap
  master
  remotes/localrepo/HEAD -> localrepo/master
  remotes/localrepo/dev-mdbootstrap
  remotes/localrepo/master
  remotes/origin/master


C:\dev> git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/MyOrganization/MyProject.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/MyOrganization/MyProject.git (push)


C:\dev> git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: https://github.com/MyOrganization/MyProject.git
  Push  URL: https://github.com/MyOrganization/MyProject.git
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branches:
    dev-mdbootstrap tracked
    master          tracked
  Local branches configured for 'git pull':
    dev-mdbootstrap merges with remote dev-mdbootstrap
    master          merges with remote master
  Local refs configured for 'git push':
    dev-mdbootstrap pushes to dev-mdbootstrap (up to date)
    master          pushes to master          (up to date)


C:\dev> git ls-remote origin
2ac96d0912e126f5ccaafef66133e3fbc3f23f1d        HEAD
bd3366870b7c6848c7d182e971307b9a74e0ae48        refs/heads/dev-mdbootstrap
2ac96d0912e126f5ccaafef66133e3fbc3f23f1d        refs/heads/master
```

I'm stumped as to why `git branch -a` still lists `localrepo` and does not show local branch `dev-mdbootstrap` tracking `remotes/origin/dev-mdbootstrap`.

An explanation of the history of this repository is needed.

I originally cloned a *local* git repository, created a new branch named `dev-mdbootstrap`, and began working. So at that point `origin` was the *local* repository.

Later, I wanted to configure an existing github.com repository as `origin`, so I did the following:

```
C:\dev> git remote rename origin localrepo

C:\dev> git remote add -t master origin https://github.com/MyOrganization/MyProject.git
```

All of this seemed to work just fine. (The https://github.com/MyOrganization/MyProject.git remote previously contained only the `master` branch.)

I pushed the local `dev-mdbootstrap` branch to the newly configured GitHub `origin` repo:

```
C:\dev> git push -u origin dev-mdbootstrap:dev-mdbootstrap
Counting objects: 100% (59/59), done.
[...snipped...]
Branch 'dev-mdbootstrap' set up to track remote branch 'dev-mdbootstrap' from 'origin'.
```

Eventually, I decided to remove the `localrepo` repository:

```
git remote rm localrepo
```

I'm very puzzled why `git branch -a` still shows `localrepo`. How can I straighten it out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Internally in Git, the existence (and stored values of) remote-tracking names are independent of whether the remote itself even exists.  That is, they are just text strings that fit the `refs/remotes/r/name` pattern, where *`r`* is a remote-name and *`name`* is a branch-name as found *on* that remote.

The `git remote` commands that update remotes—`add`, `rename`, and `rm`—are *supposed to* manage the remote-tracking names in the appropriate sub-namespace.  So when you ran `git remote rm localrepo`, this *should have* erased all the `refs/remotes/localrepo/*` names.  Apparently it didn't; tracking down why it didn't—where the bug is—would require a reproducer.

You can manually remove each "bad" name using the low-level "plumbing" command `git update-ref`, which bypasses all the normal mechanisms and goes straight into the Git internals:

```
git update-ref -d refs/remotes/localrepo/HEAD
git update-ref -d refs/remotes/localrepo/dev-mdbootstrap
git update-ref -d refs/remotes/localrepo/master
```

We'll probably never know why `git remote rm` did not clean up after itself here.

(I suspect you might have set up `origin` as a *single-branch* remote though.  Check with:

```
 git config --get-all remote.origin.fetch
```

The output should normally be a single line:

```
+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Anything else indicates an unusual setup.  Not necessarily *wrong*, just unusual.)

Comment: Thanks for all of these pointers! They set me on a course to straightening out the configuration, but it got more involved than just the `git update-ref ...` commands you provided. So I've added my own answer to lay out more detail. A little hairy. Also please note that you have one typo. The `remotes` should be `remote` in `git config --get-all remote.origin.fetch`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to run git prune?

```sh
git remote prune origin
```

You can use --dry-run to see what branches will be pruned

```sh
git remote prune origin --dry-run
```

Comment: Thanks for the `git remote prune origin --dry-run` suggestion. But the `--dry-run` command returns nothing, so I think that's not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[@torek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71289398) set me on the right course. Thanks much! The full cleanup got more involved though, so I wanted to document it in case it helps someone. (Note that, because I was not sure if I was going down the right path, I made a complete backup of my `.git` repo folder before proceeding.)

Starting from this scrambled branch configuration that I noted in the original question:

```
C:\dev> git branch -a
* dev-mdbootstrap
  master
  remotes/localrepo/HEAD -> localrepo/master
  remotes/localrepo/dev-mdbootstrap
  remotes/localrepo/master
  remotes/origin/master
```

Per [@torek's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71289398) guidance, I ran:

```
C:\dev> git update-ref -d refs/remotes/localrepo/HEAD
C:\dev> git update-ref -d refs/remotes/localrepo/dev-mdbootstrap
C:\dev> git update-ref -d refs/remotes/localrepo/master
```

This resulted in the following. Note the `ignoring broken ref` warning message:

```
C:\dev> git branch -a
warning: ignoring broken ref refs/remotes/localrepo/HEAD
* dev-mdbootstrap
  master
  remotes/origin/master
```

I fumbled forward trying to resolve this. First I reexamined `git config`, following [@torek's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71289398) suggestion. Looking at `git config --get-all ...`:

```
C:\dev> git config --get-all remote.origin.fetch
+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/localrepo/*
+refs/heads/dev-mdbootstrap:refs/remotes/origin/dev-mdbootstrap
```

Since `localrepo` still showed up in the config and I was not sure what individual `git config ...` commands would clean it up, I simply ran `git config -e` to edit the `.git\config` file in my text editor. Originally, the file contained:

```
[core]
    ...various settings... snipped out...

[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/MyOrganization/MyProject.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/localrepo/*
    fetch = +refs/heads/dev-mdbootstrap:refs/remotes/origin/dev-mdbootstrap
[branch "dev-mdbootstrap"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/dev-mdbootstrap
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

I simplified the `[remote "origin"]` section to the following, and left everything else unchanged:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/MyOrganization/MyProject.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

However, this had no impact on the `git branch -a` output.

I inspected `C:\dev\.git\refs\remotes` folder directly. It contained both an `origin` and a `localrepo` folder. The latter contained a single file named `HEAD` with the contents:

```
ref: refs/remotes/localrepo/master
```

I poked around for a way to clear this out using a `git update-ref -d ...` command, but nothing I tried worked, so I finally just deleted the ``C:\dev.git\refs\remotes\localrepo` folder manually.

This helped! After this `git branch -a` and `git branch -vv` returned the following:

```
git branch -a
* dev-mdbootstrap
  master
  remotes/origin/master

PS C:\dev> git branch -vv
* dev-mdbootstrap bd336687 [origin/dev-mdbootstrap: gone] ...snipped commit message #1...
  master          2ac96d09 [origin/master] ...snipped commit message #1...
```

But why did this show "origin/dev-mdbootstrap: **gone**"? I tried `git remote show origin`, which returned the following. Note the line `dev-mdbootstrap new (next fetch will store in remotes/origin)`.

```
C:\dev> git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: https://github.com/MyOrganization/MyProject.git
  Push  URL: https://github.com/MyOrganization/MyProject.git
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branches:
    dev-mdbootstrap new (next fetch will store in remotes/origin)
    master          tracked
  Local branches configured for 'git pull':
    dev-mdbootstrap merges with remote dev-mdbootstrap
    master          merges with remote master
  Local refs configured for 'git push':
    dev-mdbootstrap pushes to dev-mdbootstrap (up to date)
    master          pushes to master          (up to date)
```

It seems that during the time my git configuration was scrambled, my earlier commands such as `git fetch origin dev-mdbootstrap` and others to try to force the local `dev-mdbootstrap` branch to track `origin/dev-mdbootstrap` were simply having no effect.

But since git indicated a `next fetch` was needed, I ran:

```
C:\dev> git fetch origin
From https://github.com/MyOrganization/MyProject
 * [new branch]        dev-mdbootstrap -> origin/dev-mdbootstrap
```

and then:

```
C:\dev> git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/dev-mdbootstrap dev-mdbootstrap
Branch 'dev-mdbootstrap' set up to track remote branch 'dev-mdbootstrap' from 'origin'.
```

Finally, 'git branch -a -vv' returns:

```
C:\dev> git branch -a -vv
* dev-mdbootstrap                bd336687 [origin/dev-mdbootstrap] ...snipped commit message #1...
  master                         2ac96d09 [origin/master] ...snipped commit message #2...
  remotes/origin/dev-mdbootstrap bd336687 ...snipped commit message #1...
  remotes/origin/master          2ac96d09 ...snipped commit message #2...
```

Now everything looks clean, and `git` is behaving as I normally expect it to. Again, props to [@torek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71289398) for setting me on the right course. This may not be the optimal or most correct way to fix this, but it got the job done.

Comment: Wow. That bad fetch refspec was probably the main culprit, but how it got in there in the first place is a puzzle. Since fetch refspecs are unconditionally obeyed, they can do some damage. :-)